# URL for testing internet connectivity

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I connect to a guest WiFi network in a hotel or institution.  My computer shows that I'm connected to the router but not the internet.  Of course - I'm going to need to go to the institution's page and click "I agree" in response to whatever disclaimers and waivers they feel necessary.   But that page doesn't open automatically.  I have to open my browser and explicitly try to go *somewhere* - only then will the router redirect me to its legalese page.

The question is:  where should I try to go?

The problem with many obvious options is the increasing trend of organizations' landing pages to be `https` rather than `http`. That redirection must happen early, at the DNS lookup stage or something, I don't know, but it seems to thwart the redirect-to-legalese-page mechanism of most guest WiFi implementations. Typically they just hang.

Since [google.com](http://google.com) made the transition to `https`, [bing.com](http://bing.com) has been my go-to, but today I notice that it has transitioned too.

The ideal target needs to be:

- reachable via a quick-to-type URL
- reliably up
- reliably non-malicious
- unlikely to want to transition to `https`
- quick to respond to requests from as large an area of the world as possible  (there will probably be different go-to's for different regions)
- sparse on content, at least on its landing page.

Comment: http://hylia.com http://toogam.com http://cyberpillar.com may or may not support HTTPS at any given moment, but are expected to support HTTP regardless, and are not likely to be implementing HTTP to HTTPS auto-redirection in the foreseeable future.  The first one there probably has a bit of better uptime (historically).  Might not address your 5th bullet point sufficient for your likings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://NeverSSL.com/ exists for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try [THIS](http://this.com)

That is "http://this.com" I think "This" is what your looking for ;)

Comment: Looks good!  Although I don't see anything on the site, nor anything obvious from google,  about who **this** is or what their business/agenda is...